# one day gap between datepicker and php date

Tags: php, date, timezone, jquery-ui-datepicker

So I have this jQuery `datePicker` (no special configuration), it goes like:

```
$(function() {

    var startTs = new Date("' . gmdate('D M d Y', $timeStamp) . '");
    var endTs   = new Date("' . gmdate('D M d Y') . '");

    $("#datepicker_history_days").datepicker({
      dateFormat:"d MM yy",
      minDate: startTs,
      maxDate: endTs,
      onSelect: function() {
        document.getElementById("date_start_value").value = $(this).datepicker("getDate").getTime() / 1000;
      }
    });
  });'
```

let's say I chose, July the 10th 2013, in #date_start_value I have now: **1370815200**, which is the `timestamp` for **10/6/2013 à 0:00:00** and that's correct.

But later, when I want to convert the `timestamp` into date using a simple function:

```
function formatDateLang($timestamp) {
    return date('j', $timestamp).'-'.date('n', $timestamp)].'-'.date('Y', $timestamp);
}
```

I get **9 June 2013** printed (while the `timestamp` stands for **10 june 2013**).

How could I fix this ?

my server timezone is 'Europe/Paris' (GMT+2)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
//Prints 06/10/2013
echo date('m/d/Y', 1370815200);
?>
```